# HTML5 & placeholder: how to do it progressively?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, progressive-enhancement

I'm thinking about using HTML5's `placeholder` attribute. If the browser doesn't support HTML5, I can use jQuery as a fallback. However, what if JS is turned off? How do I handle this using the progressive enhancement philosophy?

Comment: Since you've said in a comment below that you don't like the semantics of using a `placeholder` to label an `input` (as is currently trendy, à la the Stack Overflow search bar), even dynamically, I guess it's safe to assume that you're looking to use placeholders for something else. What exactly is your intended use for them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you show an actual `<label>` element and hide it with js?

```
// js file
$('label').hide();
```

That way, without js, they'll see a regular label; with js, the label will be removed and you'll get either your jquery placeholder, or your html5 placeholder.

Comment: This is the only way of doing this that I can think of that's really doing "progressive enhancement." I'd modify this slightly so that your JavaScript code, instead of just hiding the label, dynamically created a `placeholder` from the `label` text, so it won't have to be duplicated in the HTML source.

Comment: Well, you're not removing the label, you're hiding it. So, semantically, you're ok. and screen readers will get the label as well.

Comment: @mozillanerd - I beg to differ. The whole point of this answer is that it produces something useful whether JS is available or not.

Comment: @mozillanerd - could you explain why you don't think this is a good rec?

Comment: It's not bad semantically, it's just that it's a compromise. This is for the "What if we can't use a placeholder?" scenario, so there may be an actual (semantic) label and then we're just adding another with the hint that would go in the placeholder if placeholder was supported.

Comment: Yes, it's semantic. Semantics is about using structural elements within the structure of your document that accurately define the contents of your document. In this answer, you're using a `<label>` to "label" your input element - you can't get much more semantic than that. The reason the spec says not to use the placeholder as an alternative to a label is because there is not "structural" advantage of a placeholder; it's an attribute. The question asked how to use progressive enhancement to take advantage of html5 placeholder when available, then fallback to a js solution, then fallback again.